# Python Selenium questions

Tags: python, selenium

So i'm trying to make an email checker too see if the email I want his username I want is taken, or isn't, but I cannot figure out how to do it

```
def check():
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]"""):
        print(user_input + " is taken")
    else:
        print("Success")
check()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If the element with `id="MemberNameError"` is only present in the DOM when there is a name error, you can try finding this element and handle the `NoSuchElementException` exception:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def check():
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]""")
        print(user_input + " is taken")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Success")
```

If the element becomes visible/invisible depending whether there is an error or not, check the element's "displayedness" via `is_displayed()` method:

```
def check():
    error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MemberNameError"]""")
    if error.is_displayed():
        print(user_input + " is taken")
    else:
        print("Success")
```

---

As a side note, there is a simpler `find_element_by_id()` locator - you don't have to use the XPath expressions always:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("MemberNameError")
```

Comment: It said success when it was taken.. this is the text
Someone already has this username

Comment: Also, NoSuchElementException is not a valid function

Comment: @Nevermind123 don't rush, the answer is now ready to be tested. I was improving it up until now. Thanks.